# How I Do Dynamic Size box

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a box that when I choose something , I want to see my choose there (like a shopping cart).
I want the box will be dynamic, which means that there will be no text overflow from the box (No text overflow down)

HTML

```
<div class="box-s">
  <p  style="text-align: left; width:49%; display: inline-block;">{{mealService.getName()}}</p>
  <p  style="text-align: right; width:49%; display: inline-block;">{{mealService.getPrice()}}$</p>
```

CSS

```
.box-s{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #9e9e9e;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-family: "Forte";
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

thanks:)

Comment: Could you make clear what you want us to help you with?

Comment: its work but I have text warping from the box buttom and i want that all the txet will be in the box dinamicly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution is in the css file need to change height to min-height

```
.box-s{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 350px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #9e9e9e;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-family: "Forte";
  font-size: 20px;
}
```